# remove trailing zeros from output

Tags: c

So my program works and compiles it does what I ask.
But my program's output has these trailing zeros that I would like to eliminate.
It's not like it bothers me but I definitely would like to have it cleaned up a little.
If anyone could give me a little insight on how to eliminate the trailing zeros your help, 
would be greatly appreciated.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#define BPR 10      // Basic Pay Rate is $10.00/hr.
#define OTPR 15     // Over Time is time and a half.
#define OT 40       // Overtime is after 40 hours.
#define RATE1 .15   // Tax Rate 15%.
#define RATE2 .20   // Tax Rate 20%.
#define RATE3 .25   // Tax Rate 25%.
#define LIMIT1 300.00  // The first 300.00.
#define LIMIT2 200.00  // 200 after the first 300.

int main(void)
{
    int hours;
    double tax;
    double gross;
    double taxes1=0,taxes2=0,taxes3=0;
    double net;
    double hold1=0,hold2=0,hold3=0;

    printf("Please enter hours worked: ");
    scanf_s("%i", &hours);
        if(hours < OT)
            gross=hours*BPR;
        else
        gross=((hours-OT)*OTPR+(OT*BPR));

    if(gross > LIMIT2 && gross < LIMIT1)
       taxes1=gross*RATE2, hold1=gross-taxes1; 
    if(gross > LIMIT1)
       taxes2=gross*RATE1, hold2=gross-taxes2;
    if(gross < LIMIT2)
       taxes3=gross*RATE3, hold3=gross-taxes3;
    if(gross > 0)
    {
       net=(hold1+hold2+hold3);
       tax=(taxes1+taxes2+taxes3);
    }

    printf("Your Net Pay is %f\n", net);
    printf("Your Gross Pay was %f\n", gross);
    printf("Your Taxes paid are %f\n", tax);



    return 0;
}
```

if 65 was put in for the hours variable the output would read:

Your Net pay is 828.750000

Your Gross Pay was 975.000000

Your Taxes paid are 146.250000

as you can see there are a lot of zeros I would love to have disappear please help ?

Comment: This really is a case of rtfm. Printf formats have many options, and any text book or man page will explain them to you.

Comment: Also (although not the question you asked) your overtime calculation is wrong, probably. If you work more than 40 hours, then according to your code you get paid overtime on all the hours worked, not just on those over 40.

Comment: yea I realized that and starting a solution to that problem now, thank you for also pointing that out.

Comment: I just fixed it:    gross=((hours-OT)*OTPR+(OT*BPR));

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `%.2f` as the output format.

Comment: Indeed, make sure you read up on `printf` (and other functions') arguments : http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/

Comment: %.2f only sets the maximum number of digits after the dot. it will eliminate the other not-zero digits from the result (you'll get an incorrect result) and if you don't have at least 2 digits after the dot you'll still have extra zeros.

Comment: @zoran404 Agree "it will eliminate the other not-zero digits", but then so does most printing of FP numbers.  Example: `printf("%f",0.123)` prints "0.123".  Given typical FP, the exact output is more like "0.122999...9999822... (about 50 digits)".  So rounding to 2 decimal places incurs the same issues of the default 6 decimal places.

Answer (score 2):

You can specify how many positions you want to display after the decimal point using `.` followed by the number of positions between `%` and `f` like so: `printf("Your Net Pay is %.2f\n", net);`. There are other formatting options that can be used with  format specifiers and you can read more on them in the man pages by doing `man printf` since `printf` is not just a `C` function.